# What is the no agressive variant (Peaceful Variant)?

Tags: through-the-ages

Yesterday I played on [Board Game Arena](https://en.boardgamearena.com) a non agressive variant of the game. The only difference I saw was a lack of wonders of age A (that could be just luck) and no agression cards.

The game itself was very boring, with nothing else to do only a rush to tackle VP without any other interaction between the players.

That's the only thing that this variation do, or there is something else that I miss??

How does the military cards are arrange in this variation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume this is the same as the "Peaceful Variant" from p19 of the [rules](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/55064/through-ages-english-rulebook):

> Remove all Aggression and War cards. You probably also want to remove the Pacts that lose their usefulness when no one can attack.

As the rules proceed to explain, this can be more fun for new players so they don't get crushed quite as badly. Military cards are acquired as normal - they are less useful without war but not totally useless (e.g. there's still Colonization). There is definitely less player interaction in this variant, but still some (e.g. competition for particular cards).